# TCP and retransmission

Tags: tcp

I'm trying to understand how the transmission and ACK work in TCP. In this Figuure, when A retransmitt the seq 100 after he recive three duplikated ACK , B will answer with 121 ACK or 158 ACK ? [image]

Comment: You'd better off asking that at [sf].

Answer (score 0):

B would only be issuing the 100 ACK because it didn't receive the SEQ 121 packet. There's no evidence that it received the next packets either, but even if it did it isn't required to save them. So the answer depends on things that aren't specified in your question.